# Trying to get info of pages from https://graph.facebook.com

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am getting data about certain pages from  https://graph.facebook.com/pages
  but i want details about posts on certain Facebook page.
  how can i do this? without use of access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) carefully, you'll find that you can not fetch the posts without using an **access token**.

But, I think you might be interested in a small work around- create an app on facebook, save the **app access token** (app_id|app_secret) and use it to get the public posts of the page.

Comment: i have made an an app, but i don't know how to move ahead now. please give some refrence

Comment: Its quite simple what I ve mentioned in the ans, what difficulty are u facing ?

Comment: your refernce has helped alot. I want to get data without logging in. basically i'm making a cron job where 'POST's' DATA will get stored in database.

Comment: access tokens work only till i'm logged in to Facebook. how to make it work when i'm logged out. please help!!! its urgent. just wanna get total number of posts on certain public pages.

Comment: Pls read the answer carefully, I said to use this token `app access token (app_id|app_secret)` - it never expires!

Comment: {
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token signature.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190
   }
}

Comment: thats what i m geting after doing what u said sir.

Comment: That means your access token is not correct, verify your token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/